# Bw tool in sphinxtrain cannot open mdef file on Windows

Tags: cmusphinx

I am developing an speech recognition application using Sphinx4. I am trying to do acoustic model adaptation. I have followed every step of the instruction on the http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt tutorial. However, in the step where i need to run the bw, it cannot open the mdef file and shows an Debug Assertion Fail.

I have been working on this for days but still dont know how to solve it. I am using Windows 10, ptm model, visual studio 2015, the latest sphinx4 5prealpha version.

Comment: You need to provide more information what exact command you run and what is the exact output you so.

Comment: i ran bw \
 -hmmdir en-us \
 -moddeffn en-us/mdef.txt \
 -ts2cbfn .ptm. \
 -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
 -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
 -cmn current \
 -agc none \
 -dictfn cmudict-en-us.dict \
 -ctlfn arctic20.fileids \
 -lsnfn arctic20.transcription \
 -accumdir .

Comment: exactly what the tutorial told me to do

Comment: So is there a file mdef.txt?

Comment: I copied the content of the mdef file into a mdef.txt placed inside en-us. I have also tried using just -moddeffn en-us/mdef

Comment: I have checked the source file of bw, it seems like the error is coming from here:

Comment: /* Read in the model definitions.  Defines the set of
       CI phones and context dependent phones.  Defines the
       transition matrix tying and state level tying. */
    if (model_def_read(&mdef, mdeffn) != S3_SUCCESS) {
 return S3_ERROR;
    }

Comment: You can try `-moddeffn en-us\mdef` since Windows expects backslashes.

Comment: it doesn't work, still the same error

Comment: You can provide the full output of the command to get help on this issue

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the answer. I think it could have been because that i forgot to download Perl or something went wrong during my installation of Sphinxbase.

I first installed Perl. However, it still didnt work, so i re-built Sphinxbase and copied it back to Sphinxtrain, and it finally run.

p/s Thanks Nikolay for your help :)

Comment: Unlikely Perl is an issue, it has no relation to binary

Answer (score 0):

This comment / solution is just based on my experience as I am not an expert on this. I had this same exact error after following all the instructions from [adapting-the-model](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialadapt/#converting-the-sendump-and-mdef-files) and looks like the mdef file from sourge-forge is corrupted. So I landed up on a comment on some other website where it mentioned to download the setup files for pocketsphinx, sphinxbase and sphinxtrain from github directly. So I downloaded it from here [GitHub](https://github.com/cmusphinx) and followed the same steps from before. Since I was working on windows, I rebuilt using VS Studio later, after upgrading the project from 2012 to latest version.

**Steps (from GitHub)-**

1. You should download and unpack it to the same parent directory as PocketSphinx, so that the configure script and project files can find it. On Windows, you will need to rename 'sphinxbase-X.Y' (where X.Y is the SphinxBase version number) to simply 'sphinxbase' for this to work.
2. To compile the SphinxTrain under MS Visual Studio 2010
3. load SphinxTrain.sln located in SphinxTrain directory
4. compile all the projects in SphinxTrain (from SphinxTrain.sln)
   MS Visual Studio will build the executables under .\bin\Release or .\bin\Debug (depending on the version you choose on MS Visual Studio), and the libraries under .\lib\Release or .\lib\Build.
5. Once you finished with compilation, copy the pocketsphinx and sphinxbase tools and dlls from sphinxbase\bin\Releae and pocketsphinx\bin\Release to sphinxtrain\bin\Release folder. This will enable you to run the training process which expects to see all the tools and libraries in sphinxtrain\bin\Release.